# Finding the Derivative of an Expected Value.

Tags: probability, statistics

Is it possible to find the derivative of an expression inside the expectation operator $ \mathbb{E}[\cdot] $? I have an expression that reads
$$
\mathbb{E} \left[ \left[ \log(A_{k}) - \log(\hat{A_{k}}) \right]^{2} ~ \Bigg| ~ (y_{t})_{0 \leq t \leq T} \right]\cdots \cdots \cdots (1)
$$
which needs to be minimised.
Then it says: *The estimator is easily shown to be*
$$
\hat{A_{k}} = \exp \left( \mathbb{E} \left[ \log(A_{k}) ~ \Big| ~ (y_{t})_{0 \leq t \leq T} \right] \right)\cdots \cdots \cdots (2)
$$
How can this be shown? Thanks!

--------EDIT--------
I have one more question
The equations said that the log in equation 2 is natural log (ln) while it is independent of the log base used in equation 1. Could you please tell me the reason for that?
Thank you very much

--------EDIT 2--------
Something related:
[Expected value and Variance](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/7178/50333)

Comment: Dear user13267, I’ve done some major editing to your question in order to make the presentation clearer.

Comment: @Haskell Curry: Thank you very much. I greatly appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: Do not edit the question long after you received answer(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One is looking for the value $a$ which yields the minimal
$$
L(a)=\mathbb E((\log A_k-\log a)^2\mid y_t,t\leqslant T).
$$
This assumes that $(\log A_k)^2$ is integrable, otherwise the function $L$ would be infinite everywhere. In such a context Lebesgue differentiation theorem indicates that indeed,
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm da}\mathbb E(G(A_k,a))=\mathbb E\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial a}G(A_k,a)\right).
$$
Here,
$$
L'(a)=-\frac2{a}\mathbb E(\log A_k-\log a\mid y_t,t\leqslant T)=-\frac2{a}\left(\mathbb E(\log A_k\mid y_t,t\leqslant T)-\log a\right),
$$
hence $L'(a)=0$ if and only if
$$
\log a=\mathbb E(\log A_k\mid y_t,t\leqslant T),
$$
that is,
$$
a=\exp\left(\mathbb E(\log A_k\mid y_t,t\leqslant T)\right).
$$
**Edit:** The reasoning above applies to every (differentiable) function $L$. In the present case, one can note that $a\mapsto L(a)$ is a quadratic polynomial in $\log a$, namely,
$$
L(a)=\mathbb E((\log A_k)^2\mid y_t,t\leqslant T)-2\mathbb E(\log A_k\mid y_t,t\leqslant T)(\log a)+(\log a)^2.
$$
Since the polynomial $x\mapsto\gamma-2\beta x+x^2$ is minimal when $x=\beta$, the likelihood $a\mapsto L(a)$ is minimal when $\log a=\mathbb E(\log A_k\mid y_t,t\leqslant T)$.

Comment: is there an easier alternative way or a more intuitive way to understand this?

Comment: See Edit. $ $ $ $

Comment: ok Thank you very much. Could you please give some more idea about the polynomial being minimum when x=beta part? How can I know that which value of x gives minimum value for any expression?

Comment: First question: $\gamma-2\beta x+x^2=\gamma-\beta^2+(\beta-x)^2$. Second question: ANY expression? Well, derivative zero, if you can.

Comment: ok I understand now. Thank you very much.

Comment: sorry I have one more question: how did you remove log a from the expectation operator?

Comment: Where exactly? $ $

Comment: I meant in the edited part; you have used the formula for $ (a+b)^2 $ and applied the expectation operator to all the individual expressions except for log a; why can log a be removed from inside the expectation operator? I thought only constants could be removed from the expectation operator

Comment: Exactly. And $\log a$ is what you call a constant (that is, not random).

Comment: but the $ a $ from $ log\, a $ is the estimated value and it is what needs to be ultimately calculated. How can it be considered constant?

Comment: Oh I see. Then we are back at square one of the principles of pointwise estimation. Let me be brief: (1) The solution is correct. (2) You might want to grab any book on the subject and to scan it separating mentally what is random from what is deterministic. (3) Your own equation `(2)` defines a **deterministic** $\hat A_k$ (naturally).

Comment: And about the logs: changing their base multiplies `(1)` by a scalar constant hence it does not modify the rest of the procedure.

Comment: I know the solution is correct and I appreciate the time that you have given to my question; WhaT I don't understand is that a is an estimate for the input signal A, but since A cannot be measured directly we have to use it's estimate, that is, a; thus I suppose value of a changes according to that of A. Then if I should be kept inside the expectation operator, shouldn't a go as well? I am sure I am wrong here somewhere as I know your answer is correct, I need to know which place I am wrong in.

Comment: Also likelihood function had been mentioned here; I searched around for likelihood functions and their properties as well, but it is more confusing

Comment: or is it the fact that $ a $ is in fact calculated from something or depends on something ( $ A_K $ ) which makes it 'not random' ?

Comment: @Ufos "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner."

Comment: @Did still, taking the derivative this way is a  consequence of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement

(for anyone, who will ever wonder why is the derivative moved into the expectation)